# How do you open video with uri from youtube.I want it to open in a video player within the app

Tags: forms, xamarin

I want the video to play within the app

```
 public void view(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        StackLayout listViewItem = (StackLayout)button.Parent;
        Label label = (Label)listViewItem.Children[3];
        String text = label.Text;
        Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + text));
    }
```

Comment: You could define the webview in xaml and set the source in code behind like the following answer . For the usage of Webview you could check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1):

You could add a webview to your page. Then set the source property of the webview to an HtmlWebSource which is just an iFrame that has the embedded url of the YouTube video in it.

```
var myUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/QR-tZqiKCrg";

var myWebSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();

myWebSource.Html = $"<div align='center'><iframe width='95%' Height='40%' src = '{myUrl}' frameborder = '0' allowfullscreen='1'></iframe></div>";

MyWebView.Source = myWebSource;
```

Comment: Where do you implement this?